# Vue: How to extend exist directive with new modifiers

Tags: vue.js, directive

How extend exist directive like: `v-on` with my custom `modifiers`.
For example provided `debounce` ability with `.deb` `modifiers`.

For example:

```js
<btn v-on:click.deb="myFn"> click me </btn>
```

So basically in this case it needed to capture `myFn`  before it goes to `addEventListener` and warp it with *debounce* function. And then move it to regular `v-on` directive to continue the process.

How could I achieve that ?

I know I can create `my-new-directive` that do the whole process but then is not generic.
And it easier to warp the function in the source and done with that.

But more impotent I want to learn the Vue way to how to extend exist directive.

---

After digging in the old docs I see that in the past Vue achieve `debounce` with `filter`

```js
<btn v-on:click="myFn | debounce 300"> click me </btn>
```

But that removed from the current version ( 2.x ) for preferred warping the function in the source. I personally less like it because it takes more scrolled to warp big function

Comment: Cool question, I've never heard of anyone doing this. I found https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7846 but I'm not sure it's what you want.

Comment: cool that you research that a bit. the reference you mention (from 2018) talk about multiple registers to `v-on` with different `modifiers`